# Recursive function in Redux

Tags: javascript, recursion, react-redux, preact

Trying to pass a reference to the recursive function to check if Redux action data fetch is complete, but getting function reference errors

```
const fetchAccountComplete = (state, accountNo) =>  { //state here is function reference
    
    return new Promise(resolve => { 
        
         (function waitForFetchComplete(state, accountNo) {
            
            const {isFetching, receivedAt} = state().account[accountNo] // getting state not a function here
            if (!isFetching) return resolve()
            setTimeout(waitForFetchComplete, 100)
        })()
        
    })
}
```

Is there a better way to return a promise to the caller function in Redux dispatch actions so that once the data is fetched, i need to do some other logic in other action.

Update 1:

should have been more clearer. There are two callers of this Request, Recieve actions on say Account data. First caller is directed similar to the above comment by you so waits until complete, second caller would not be doing the async call again and need to check if data fetch is complete so trying to see if recursive function with check on state so that promise can be resolved is being done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take advantage of promising chaining.
Example:

Have three actions like: IS_FETCHING, FETCH_SUCCESS, FETCH_ERROR.

IS_FETCHING:
Will simply set your state as pending (may be useful for showing a loading animation, for example).

FETCH_SUCCESS:
Will contain the result of the fetch to update the state. Will also clear the isUpdating flag

FETCH_ERROR:
Will contain any possible error due to the fetch (application or network error). Will also clear the isUpdating flag

Then, what you could do at application level is:

```javascript
dispatch({type: IS_FETCHING, payload: data});
fetch(`https://MY-SERVER.com/?data=${data}`)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json =>
     dispatch({
       type: isError(json) ? FETCH_RESULT : FETCH_ERROR,
       payload: json
     })
  );
```

You could even benefit of action creators for the job.
Here is a good guide for that: https://redux.js.org/advanced/async-actions

Comment: Thanks for the comment, should have been more clearer. There are two callers of this Request, Recieve actions on say Account data. First caller is directed similar to the above comment by you so waits until complete, second caller would not be doing the async call again and need to check if data fetch is complete so trying to see if recursive function with check on state so that promise can be resolved is being done.

Comment: I see, so rephrasing to be clear if I understand: 

you have different components needing the same data but you need to avoid having two exact same calls.
Am I Right?

If so, why not deciding which of the components needs to do the call? 

If you can't decide (e.g. you can't tell before hand how the components will be used), how about extracting the caller to a third element, having the two original components acting only by displaying the data at store level?

Comment: @Guilhermevrs That is a terrible idea, now you have multiple components needing to coordinate whether or not to make an api call. Or you make the api call in a component that doesn't even need it. This will needlessly complicate your code and make it more difficult to change when requirements change.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a function that returns a promise that is called multiple times with the same arguments then you can group that in a way so that the function is not called when it still has an unresolved promise and something tries to call it again with the same arguments.

Here is an example:

```js
//group promise returning function
const createGroup = (cache) => (
  fn,
  getKey = (...x) => JSON.stringify(x)
) => (...args) => {
  const key = getKey(args);
  let result = cache.get(key);
  if (result) {
    return result;
  }
  //no cache
  result = Promise.resolve(fn.apply(null, args)).then(
    (r) => {
      cache.done(key); //tell cache promise is done
      return r;
    },
    (e) => {
      cache.done(key); //tell cache promise is done
      return Promise.reject(e);
    }
  );
  cache.set(key, result);
  return result;
};
//creates a cache that will remove cached value when
//  Promise is done (resolved or rejected)
const createCache = (cache = new Map()) => {
  return {
    get: (key) => cache.get(key),
    set: (key, value) => cache.set(key, value),
    done: (key) => cache.delete(key),
  };
};

//function that retuns a promise
const later = (time, value) => {
  console.log('executing later with values', time, value);
  return new Promise((r) =>
    setTimeout(() => r(value), time)
  );
};
//create group function with a cache that will remove
//  cache key when promise is resolved or rejected
const groupAndRemoveCacheOnDone = createGroup(
  createCache()
);
//grouped version of the later function
const groupedLater = groupAndRemoveCacheOnDone(later);
//testing the groped later
groupedLater(100, 8); //first call causes console.log
groupedLater(100, 8); //same arguments will not call later
groupedLater(100, 8); //will not call later
//will call later because arguments are not the same
//  as the other calls
groupedLater(100, 'XX');
groupedLater(100, 8) //will not call later
  .then((value) => {
    console.log('resolved with:', value);
    //this will call later because cache value is removed
    //  after promise is resolved
    return groupedLater(100, 8);
  })
  .then(() => {
    //testing with fetchAccountComplete
    console.log(
      '***** how many times is fetchAccountComplete called *****'
    );
    const fetchAccountComplete = (state, accountNo) => {
      console.log(
        'fetchAccountComplete called with',
        accountNo
      );
      return new Promise((resolve) => {
        (function waitForFetchComplete(state, accountNo) {
          const {
            isFetching,
            receivedAt,
          } = state().account[accountNo]; // getting state not a function here
          if (!isFetching) return resolve();
          setTimeout(
            () => waitForFetchComplete(state, accountNo),
            100
          );
        })(state, accountNo);
      });
    };
    const data = {
      account: [{ isFetching: true }],
    };
    const state = () => data;
    const groupedFetchAccountComplete = groupAndRemoveCacheOnDone(
      fetchAccountComplete
    );

    groupedFetchAccountComplete(state, 0);
    groupedFetchAccountComplete(state, 0);
    groupedFetchAccountComplete(state, 0);
    groupedFetchAccountComplete(state, 0).then((resolve) =>
      console.log('resolved')
    );
    data.account[0].isFetching = false;
  });
```